# Flutter slider should scroll only when dragged with thumb bar

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-layout

In my custom widgets, there are multiple components along with the scrolling of page. Whenever I accidentally touch nearby to a slider by, it is recognizing touch & changing the position to respective position. I need custom behavior so that Slider changes only when it is dragged with a thumb bar.

I tried by adding a gesture recognizer on top of the slider but gives the flicker effect of changing & resetting value. Is it possible so that Slider shouldn't react on touch other than drag?

```
 GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (updateDetails) {
          print("On onHorizontalDragUpdate called");
          setState(() {
            _diffLevel = updateDetails.globalPosition.distance;
          });
        },
        onTap: (() {
          setState(() {
            _diffLevel = _diffLevel;
          });
          print("On Tap called");
        }),
        child: Slider.adaptive(
              value: _diffLevel.toDouble(),
              activeColor: MyColors.appMediumBlueColor(),
              //inactiveColor: Colors.purple,
              onChanged: (double newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _diffLevel = newValue;
                });
              },
              min: widget.minLevel,
              max: widget.maxLevel,
              divisions: widget.divisions,
              label: _diffLevel.toString(),
            ),
      )
```

Expected Result :

[image: Only Drag gesture should work]

Actual result:

[image: Tap gesture anywhere on slider bar reacts]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/121483 This should be merged soon and then there will be a built-in way of defining the slider tap behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a slider implementation that allows only the drag without the jumping. That means, the slider should move only to nearby values and shouldn't jump to values that are further away.

This can easily be handled in the onchanged. From your code, you are saving the slider value in a global variable _diffLevel. Let's say, your each division is 50.

So, your onChanged could be this:

```
onChanged: (double newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    double diff = (newValue - _diffLevel).abs();
                    if(diff<=50) {
                      _diffLevel = newValue;
                    }
                  });
                },
```

This constraints the slider to change its value only when the difference between its current value and new value is within the range of 50 ie. in range of 50 around the current value. So when you click further way, it wont change. It will only change when you slide it to the next division or the previous division.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't analysed your code yet, but is there any reason no to use `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_range_slider` ?

Comment: thanks for sharing this.
 My problem is whenever user taps on slider bar it changes the position which I don't want only dragging with dragger/notch it should change

Answer (score 0):

**replace your Slider.adaptive with CupertinoSlider widget it gave same functionality what you want.....**

```
CupertinoSlider(
   value: currentPage.toDouble(),
     min: 0,
     max: 100,
     onChanged: (value) {
       // do thing with value
     },
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way I found that's I think similar to what you want is to check in the "onChanged" body if the new slider value is close enough to the current value.  If not, just ignore it.  I tested this just now, and I can go up and down but it will NOT let me accidentally press way off the thumb control.

this is critical for me since my slider is volume control and it's also in a scrollable list so rarely you might be scrolling up and down and the touch is seen as a slider touch instead of a up/down list scroll.

```
              child: Slider(
                value: playersVol[index],
                onChanged: (newVol) {
                  if ((newVol - playersVol[index]).abs() < 10) {
                    setState(() {
                      players[index].volume = newVol.toInt();
                      Provider.of<PlayersModel>(context, listen: false)
                          .setVolume(players[index].macAddr, newVol.toInt());
                    });
                  }
                },
                max: 100,
                min: 0,
              ),
```